# Two properties related to semisimple rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a semisimple ring

Show the following

(i) If $xy=1 \in R$, then $yx=1$.

(ii) If $x \in R$ is such that $xR$ is a left ideal of $R$, then $xR=Rx$.

I am pretty lost with the two items. I mean, the only think I can think of is that $R$ is a direct summand of finite simple ideals, but I don't see how that relates to these two properties. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Artin-Wedderburn theorem? Maybe it can help.

Comment: Do you mean that $R \cong M_{n_1}(D_1) \oplus ... \oplus M_{n_k}(D_k)$ with each $D_i$ a division ring? I don't see how this can be related.

Comment: It can be very useful to show point (i).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399540/prove-that-semi-simple-rings-are-dedekind-finite

Answer (score 2):

The first question has been answered [a few times before](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399798/29335) in other posts, so let's reduce duplication by pointing you to one. More generally, any Noetherian ring has the property that $xy=1$ implies $yx=1$ (a ring like this is called a *Dedekind finite ring*.)

But I don't actually recall seeing the second question before.

The second part is an easy conclusion from the fact that the ideals of $R$ are just products of the various simple components of $R$. For each ideal $I$, we have that $I=eR$ for some central idempotent $e$, and $I$ is a semisimple ring with identity $e$.

So in particular for $xR=eR$, we have that $xy=e$ for some $y\in eR$. By the first part, $yx=e$ also, and so $xR=eR=Re=Ryx\subseteq Rx$. Finally, the hypothesis says that $Rx\subseteq xR$. Thus $xR=Rx$.

Comment: I love you @rschwieb (Mathematically :) )